# C++ invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' Arduino Uno

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-c++

I've already gone through the following links but couldn't get it to work:

> [Adding to c* invalid conversion from const char* to char*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8420304/adding-to-c-invalid-conversion-from-const-char-to-char)
>
> [Why is conversion from string constant to 'char*' valid in C but invalid in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20944784/why-is-conversion-from-string-constant-to-char-valid-in-c-but-invalid-in-c)

I'm working on arduino Uno. I need to send an argument of type `char*` to a function. I have the following code:

```
const char* topic = "SampleTopic";
const char* msg = "Hello";
publish(0, 0, 0, "msgid", topic, msg);
```

I'm getting this error:

> initializing argument 5 of 'void GSM_MQTT::publish(char, char, char, unsigned int, char*, char*)'
>
> void publish(char DUP, char Qos, char RETAIN, unsigned int MessageID, char *Topic, char *Message);
>
> warning: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive]
>
> publish(0, 0, 0, _generateMessageID(), topic, msg);
>
> ```
>                                               ^
> ```

I've even tried using `const std::string& topic = "SampleTopic";` but get this error:

> 'string' in namespace 'std' does not name a type

Even `const char* topic = (char*)"SampleTopic";` and passing it as `func(topic)` gives the same error.

How can I resolve this ??

Comment: Strings and string literals is an area where C and C++ differs. You have to remember that C and C++ are two very distinct and different languages, with different semantic rules and constructs.

Comment: As for your `std::string` error, Arduino may use C++ but IIRC it doesn't use the standard C++ library. Instead it have its own class-library, where you have for example a [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class.

Comment: Oh and the first error you get doesn't match the first code snippet, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And you should never convert a `const` *anything* to non-const. You could cast `const` away, but it's almost always a bad idea. The error message, by the way, contains a hint about why you get the warning (you pass a `const char *` to a function that expects a `char *`).

Comment: If you are sure that `publish` does not modify the strings pointed to by `Topic` and `Message`, you could use an ugly cast to cast away the `const`: `publish(0, 0, 0, (char *)topic, (char *)msg);`. If `publish` is under your control, it would be better to change `publish` to use `const char *` parameters.

Comment: @IanAbbott using `(char*)"Topic Name"` but it gives me `ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to 'char*'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't known anything about the `GSM_MQTT::publish()` function but if it **requires** some modifiable strings (`char *` without `const`) for `Topic` and `Message`, then you have to provide **modifiable** strings.

```
char topic[] = "SampleTopic";
char msg[] = "Hello";
```

(you have to make sure the storage is sufficient for the modifications)

On the other hand, if this function does **not** actually require some modifiable strings, then it is probably a mistake in the API and these parameters should have been declared `const char *`.
**If** this is actually the case, you can safely use `const_cast` (or even a traditional C *cast*) when passing your two `const char *` arguments.

```
const char* topic = "SampleTopic";
const char* msg = "Hello";
publish(0, 0, 0, ???msgid???, const_cast<char *>(topic), const_cast<char *>(msg));
```

Note that in your example you use the string `"msgid"` where an `unsigned int` is expected.

Comment: According to the library code these parameters are not modified inside and could be declared const(and it should be if it should be const correct).